# question about the notation $C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\bar{\Omega})$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The notation $C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\bar{\Omega})$ seems to be prevalent in PDE. Suppose that $u$ is a solution of the PDE and that $u$ is $C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\bar{\Omega})$.

Does it make sense to adopt this notation when $\Omega$ is an unbounded region? Or is this notation only for $\Omega$ bounded.

I was thinking of an example, say in $\mathbb{R}$, wherein if my "region" is the set of rationals then it is of course unbounded. In this case, my closure, $\bar{\Omega}$ is the set of irrationals which does not make the above notation absurd.

Comment: Generally $\Omega$ is supposed to be open.

Comment: Alright. But $\Omega$ open can be bounded or unbounded...right?

Comment: If we're dealing with PDE, that's certainly important (otherwise defining derivatives gets tricky). There's little point in allowing $\Omega$ to be disconnected, too. However, I do think unbounded regions are just fine.

Comment: It can be any open set.

Comment: What this is supposed to mean is that $u$ is a function which is twice differentiable in $\Omega$ and *can be* extended to a continuous function on $\overline{\Omega}$. So this idea makes sense for any open set. For example if you take $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ then the space consists of all $C^2$ functions that have a limit at infinity.

Comment: Alright the reason why I'm asking this is that the PDE book by Evans introduces Green's functions on $U$ open and bounded which gives rise to the representation formula for the solution of the Dirichlet problem.

Comment: Well what is the problem, precisely? Are you asking whether one can find Green's functions for unbounded domains? (The answer is yes, there are formulas when $\Omega$ is a half-space, and I think these are even presented in Evans' book).

Comment: I also just realized that, since $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R}$, I made a rather stupid mistake in my previous comment about $C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega})$. A better example of this space for unbounded $\Omega$ is to take $\Omega = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Then the space consists of all $C^2$ functions on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0} u(x)$ exists.